# Googlebot is not fetching and rendering all my content if I have a DFP ad in a list

Tags: seo, javascript, google-dfp, google-publisher-tags

I am working on reactjs. I have a an infinite scroll component to render and I am adding DFP ads at certain positions in the `<li>` tag. I have a DFP in my list like:

```
    <ul>
    <li>hello world</li>
    <li>hello world</li>
    <li>DFP here</li>
    <li>hello world</li>
    <li>hello world</li>
    <ul>
```

My content is not visible to the Google bot when I tested it on "Fetch As Google". It removes the whole list instead of removing only the ad.

But when I use this code after removing DFP from the list like:

```
   <ul>
   <li>hello world</li>
   <li>hello world</li>
   <li>hello world</li>
   </ul>
```

Now my content is available to bot.

Why is bot not fetching the content in the first code snippet just ignoring the DFP. Why it is ignoring the whole `<ul>` tag.

Comment: The issue with this is there is no definite answer unless you ask Google. Someone could guess but there is no documentation of what it will and won't render. Nor how it decides to reject elements based on ad code. You're not likely to get help.